# Can listbox be displayed as a table

Tags: c#, mysql, listview, listbox, windows-store-apps

I have listbox item in my windows store app. When i am getting data from mysql database it is not looking nice. Shows in screenshot

[image]

I want to display it as a table and with clear formatting

here is my XAML code for the listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="253" Margin="564,60,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="397" d:IsHidden="True">
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="itm"/>
    </ListBox>
```

and here is my C# code for the view button

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = @"SELECT * FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_department`;";
            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            conn.Open();
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();// this query will be executed and data saved into the database.           
            while (MyReader.Read())
            {
                //this.branchIDInput.Text = MyReader.GetString(1);
                    ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
                    itm.Content = MyReader.GetString(0) + "         " + MyReader.GetString(1) + "       " + MyReader.GetString(2);
                   this.listbox2.Items.Add(itm);
                //ListBox a = new ListBox();
                // a.Items.Add();
                    //ListViewItem ad = new ListViewItem();


            }
            conn.Close();               
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }
    }
```

Comment: datagrid is not there in windows store apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Listview

```
<ListView Name="xlistview">

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="80" Header="ID" />
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="140" Header="Name" />
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dept, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Header="Department" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>


</ListView>
```

Comment: im getting data from mysql database see my question

Answer (score 0):

No problem, write a model that can hold the values

loop through  while (MyReader.Read()) and store them into list and just bind list as itemssource to your listview.

Comment: Can you show me how can I do that, give me some example at least, or get my code and show me

Comment: here is error what im getting when try put this code into XAML `Error 4 The attachable property 'View' was not found in type 'ListView'.
`

Answer (score 0):

Helpful links
http://www.decossoftdev.com/insight/blog/2013/08/08/Developing-Windows-8-Store-Application-FlipView-GridView-and-ListView

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh943062.aspx

Listview with Itemtemplate

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/12/07/windows-8-1-listviews-gridviews-listviewitempresenter-gridviewitempresenter.aspx